# django-python3-ldap Search Users belonging to Specific Group in Active Directory

Tags: python, django, active-directory, ldap

I have `django-python3-ldap` included in my Django project, and I have it pointed at an Active Directory server. It connects to the AD server and returns a the username, first name, and hashed password to the `auth_user` table. How do I limit the search to only users in a specific AD group?

Here are the relevant settings:

```
LDAP_AUTH_SEARCH_BASE = "OU=******,DC=ad,DC=******,DC=org"
LDAP_AUTH_USER_FIELDS = {
     "username": "samaccountname",
     "first_name": "givenname",
     "last_name": "surname",
     "email": "EmailAddress",
}
LDAP_AUTH_OBJECT_CLASS = "User"
LDAP_AUTH_USER_LOOKUP_FIELDS = ("username",)
LDAP_AUTH_FORMAT_USERNAME = "django_python3_ldap.utils.format_username_active_directory"
LDAP_AUTH_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_DOMAIN = "AD"
LDAP_AUTH_FORMAT_SEARCH_FILTERS = "django_python3_ldap.utils.format_search_filters"
```

I believe I need to use `LDAP_AUTH_FORMAT_SEARCH_FILTERS` to "and" conditions to the original search base, but I'm not sure exactly how to do so. I assume I need to write a custom `format_search_filter`, but I don't intuitively understand how it would cross-check with AD groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to do the filtering with this particular package is documented [here](https://github.com/etianen/django-python3-ldap#custom-user-filters). Right in the example, it shows how you can filter using group membership. The following would limit the search to the AD group "foo"

```
# settings.py
LDAP_AUTH_FORMAT_SEARCH_FILTERS = "path.to.your.custom_format_search_filters"

# path/to/your/module.py
from django_python3_ldap.utils import format_search_filters

def custom_format_search_filters(ldap_fields):
    # Add in simple filters.
    ldap_fields["memberOf"] = "foo"
    # Call the base format callable.
    search_filters = format_search_filters(ldap_fields)
    return search_filters
```

You could alternatively (or additionally) apply rules using usual LDAP filtering syntax...

```
search_filters.append("(|(memberOf=groupA)(memberOf=GroupB))")
```

You can read up more on filtering syntax [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx) and many other places.

Comment: Apologies - I saw that portion of the docs earlier and promptly forgot they existed. I have set up my code exactly like you have yours, but now the user lookup is failing. I have my object class set to User currently, but Person provides the same result.